# Webservice unavailable when packaged in EAR

Tags: java, web-services, jboss7.x

We have a webservice which is included in an ejb-jar within an ear. That jar is then deployed to a JBoss 7.2.0.Final instance.

According to [this JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JAX-WS+User+Guide) using webservice annotations on the session bean should be sufficient.

Thus the webservice looks like this:

```
@WebService(name = "TestWS", targetNamespace="http://test.com/ws")
@WebContext(contextRoot="/test-ws", urlPattern="/*", transportGuarantee="NONE", secureWSDLAccess=false)
@Stateless  
public class TestWS
{
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHello()
  {
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

When the ear is deployed exploded everything works fine. The problem is, when deploying the packaged ear (.ear-file) the service doesn't seem to be available.

Management console displays this information in both cases:

```
Context: test-ws
Type: JAXWS_EJB3
WSDL Url: http://localhost:8080/test-ws?wsdl
```

During startup the following is logged in both cases:

```
 [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS024061: Adding service  
   endpoint metadata: id=TestWS
   address=http://localhost:8080/test-ws
   implementor=com.test.TestWS
   serviceName={http://test.com/ws}TestWSService
   portName={http://test.com/ws}TestWSPort
   annotationWsdlLocation=null
   wsdlLocationOverride=null    
   mtomEnabled=false
 ...
[org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-9) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/test-ws
```

When the ear is exploded opening `http://localhost:8080/test-ws?wsdl` retrieves the wsdl, when the ear is packaged, I get the following result:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /test-ws
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
JBWEB000068: message /test-ws
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
```

Any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: is it working with Endpoint#publish?

Comment: @PhilippSander isn't `Endpoint#publish` meant for non-AS use? Do you mean I should call it from another service during startup?

Comment: yes. but does it work?

Comment: Isn't that error simply telling you that when the application is packaged as an ear, the context name of the application is not as you expect it to be (/test-ws) ?

Comment: @PhilippSander I added `Endpoint.publish( "http://<my-ip>:8080/test-ws", new TestWS() );` to a service at startup and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced this in many projects. Any one of the below ways might work :)

1.) Package a WAR within the EAR and have web.xml which will give a kick-start to your webservices

2.) Try to load the jar in `META-INF/application.xml` which will perfectly include your JAR file.

The application.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>project-name</display-name>
  <module>
    <java>your_jar_file_name</java>
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll consider using approach 1 if there isn't any other option. Approach 2 doesn't work as well since the jar module is already present in application.xml.

Comment: After some more testing and searching I found that the service had been deployed as a webservice but not as an ejb. So fixing that resolved the issue as well (the solution is close to your approach no. 1 :) )